# DRF parses number array as string

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, form-data

When I make a POST request from JavaScript to my Django Rest Framework backend, my array of numbers is interpreted as string on the backend, causing this error:
`cargo: ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]`

This is how I make the request in JavaScript:

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append("cargo", JSON.stringify([1, 2]));
fetch(url, {method: "POST", body: data}).then(//<more code>
```

In my Django Rest Framework serializer, I define the cargo field like this:

```py
cargo = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(                                                     
    many=True, queryset=models.CustomCargo.objects.all()                                        
)
```

On the backend `request.data.get('cargo')` is the string `"[1,2]"`. I need to use multipart/form-data because I'm posting a file too, so I can't use application/json, which does work. Is there a way to fix this in the JavaScript code (I'd rather not convert strings to integers on the backend)?

Comment: Just a guess. What if you use `data.append("cargo", [1, 2]);`?

Comment: That's not allowed, [FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) accepts a string or a blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding each item of the array to the `FormData` separately as strings:

```js
[1, 2].forEach((cargo) => data.append("cargo", cargo.toString()));
```

If anybody has insight into why this works, please share.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I'd forgotten that this is the correct way to set multiple values. It's part of the spec. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append